# Angular order array of object in reverse

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Cant get this to work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="serv in servicesAdded |orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{serv.stepNumber}}</td>...
```

In my controller :

```
    $scope.predicate = 'stepNumber';
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.order = function (predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
```

My array of objects looks like this

```
  $scope.servicesAdded = [{stepNumber:-1,otherData:""},
                          {stepNumber:-2,otherData:""},
                          {stepNumber:1,otherData:""}];
```

I never comes out in reverse order (-2 first) what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try syntax with '+predicate', '-predicate'

```
<tr ng-repeat="serv in servicesAdded |orderBy:usedPredicate">
    <td>{{serv.stepNumber}}</td>...
```

and Angular code:

```
$scope.order = function (predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.usedPredicate = $scope.reverse ? '-' : '+' + predicate;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
```

> An expression can be optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name). If no property is provided, (e.g. '+') then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting.

[orderBy Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)